# Elastic Beanstalk, Circle CI and Laravel automatic deployments

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, circleci

I'm currently working on an application which I would love to deploy using Elastic Beanstalk, with Circle CI running the workflow and tests.

I'm currently in a position where, upon merging code into Master, circle CI runs a workflow and deploys the code to Elastic Beanstalk. This all works wonderfully.

My current issue, is to do with migrating the database. I have configured my environment variables in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration area, and if I ssh onto the box I can run `php artisan migrate` no worries.

I however, would like to run `php artisan migrate --force` upon every deployment, automatically.

I've experimented with `.ebextensions` and hooks. See:

```
container_commands:
  01_init:
    command: |
      mv .env.example .env
      sudo chmod  -R 755 /var/app/current/storage
      php artisan migrate --force
```

but this *always* fails with an error simular to:

```
  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27
```

(The actual error is):

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

It's almost as if it is unable to use the pre-set environment variables available on the Elastic Beanstalk instance while it runs this script, so it falls back to the defaults.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I don't want to have my sensitive credentials in the git repo (if I can avoid it).

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `.env` file configured correctly? Because it seems like a database authentication error.

Comment: I think you missed the point bud. @rkg the env variables are available on the box but not available at the point the `ebextension` is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this script in post deployment hooks folder, not sure but I guess env variables would be defined at this time

https://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/